# How do I write predictive text algorithm in Java?

Tags: algorithm, text, prediction, trie, n-gram

I need to write predictive text algorithm.
For instance given `I was there the other day` as data set, and then `I was there the other` -> I should return `day`.

My first thought was using a `Trie` data structure. I got a hint I should use `n-grams`, but so far I have not seen any explanation or algorithm on how `n-grams` connect with text prediction.

Can someone explain me this idea? Or am I right I should use `tries`?